# Groovy: Cannot cast object 'true' with class 'java.lang.Boolean' to class 'java.io.File'

Tags: file-io, groovy, junit

I don't understand why I am getting the following error. Any thoughts?

I am getting error:

`Cannot cast object 'true' with class 'java.lang.Boolean' to class 'java.io.File'`

This is the code producing the error at line 'if (envProp.exists()...':

```
static private File envProp = new File('env.properties')
static private File envPropBak = new File('env.properties.bak')

@BeforeClass
static void beforeAll() {
    if (envProp.exists()) {
        envPropBak.write( envProp.text )
    }
}
```

I don't understand why `envProp.exists()` is trying to cast anything as another object. Method `.exists()` should just return a `boolean`.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any kind of mocks? Could you put more code to see if anything else is conflicting (parent class for test class or something)

Comment: Any feedback? I'm actually interested in this case. Did my answer helped you? Was it anything else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem today, but in my case was:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'true' with class 'java.lang.Boolean' to class 'java.util.List'
```

The thing is that if your have something like this:

```
public List<Foo> method(){
    methodThatReturnsTrue()
}
```

Because Groovy uses the last sentence's return as the method's return value, it tries to cast true to `<some_not_boolean_type>` and so the error you and I are getting.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness I need to say that I got a similar message:

> Cannot cast object 'true' with class 'java.lang.Boolean' to class
>   'java.util.List'

When I invoked:

```
final List<String> reportedChangedFiles = linesOfChangedFiles.removeAll([null])
```

I was expecting removeAll() to return a new collection but I forgot that it modifies the current collection and returns a boolean instead. So it was as easy as:

```
linesOfChangedFiles.removeAll([null])
```

Answer (score 0):

That was a bug and got fixed in newer versions (2.3.2):
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-6810

Answer (score 0):

I got that exception after capturing the argument on a method invocation, trying to check one of the fields of the object.

```
MyRepository repository = Mock()    

def "MyTest"(){
  ...
  
  then:
  1 * repository.save(_) >> {
      MyEntity entity = (Entity) it[0]
      entity.name == "expectedName" 
  }
}
```

It seems that inside that kind of blocks usual assertions do not work. I fixed the problem using `assert`

```
def "MyTest"(){
  ...
  
  then:
  1 * repository.save(_) >> {
      MyEntity entity = (Entity) it.get(0)
      assert entity.name == "expectedName" 
  }
}
```

Now it works like a charm :-)

P.S I also replaced `it[0]` by `it.get(0)` to get rid of an IntelliJ warning message

> 'getAt' in 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods' cannot
> be applied to '(java.lang.Integer)'